# Multithreaded logger

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I am trying to create a logger for multithreaded c++ code using boost. Here's my code:

```
class logger
{
private:
    boost::mutex logMtx;
public:
    logger()
    {
    }
    ~logger()
    {
    }
    void logString(string z)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(logMtx);
        std::cout<<z<<std::endl;
        std::cout.flush();      
    }
};
```

Then I share an instance (The instance is created in main thread before creating other threads)  of this with multiple threads and call the logString function for logging. It does not seem to work. Some lines are coming truncated (Whole string is not printing - i.e if I pass "abcd" it prints "bcd" sometimes).

Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: A similar question some time back, Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923233/logging-in-multi-threaded-application-using-mutex-in-a-constructor/15923581

Comment: Is there any other code that could possibly be writing to `stdout`?

Comment: No other code is writting to cout.

Comment: Are you sure you are sharing an instance and not copy-constructing instead? 

Declaring them as deleted will ensure this is not happening
`logger(const logger &)=delete;
logger &operator=(const logger &)=delete;`

Although not connected, `logString()` could also take a reference to a const `string` as well.

Comment: @marko, `logger` is already non-copyable as `boost::mutex` is not copyable.

Comment: There no copying - only sharing of logger.

Comment: Simple 'lock, write' unlock' designs inflict any output stream delays, (disk/network/whatever), onto all callers.  This introduces latency that is often unacceptable.  Queueing log output to one, dedicated logger thread is usually a better solution.

Comment: Make the mutex "static".

Comment: Note that you flush it twice: `std::endl` does flushing as well as `.flush()`.

Comment: Please disregard this question. the issue was not due to mutithredaing but some data corruption. Apologies from my side